# How do I add a column(average_user_rating) to the dataframe that gives me the average rating for the userId in that row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Python dataframes:

I got a dataframe with UserId, MovieId and rating (length 81116).

[image]

I also have a series that has the average rating of each UserId (length 610).

[image]
[average rating series view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIfgX.png)

How do I add a column, average_user_rating, to the dataframe that gives me the average rating for the userId in that row?

Comment: Could you kindly provide an expected output?

Comment: My expected output will be the dataframe with a new column that display's the average user ratings for the user in that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).
It works like a SQL `JOIN`

A possible code would be:

```
df = pd.merge(left=movies_df, right=users_df, how='left', 
              left_on='userId', right_index=True)
```

Comment: Converted my series into a dataframe, and the merge technique worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the series is in UserId's crescent order, you can do it using pandas with something like:

```
df["average_user_rating"] = df["UserId"].apply(lambda x: s[x-1])
```

You can test:

```
s = pd.Series([10,20])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,5],[1,15],[2,10],[2,30]], columns = ["UserId", "Rating"])
print (s)
print (df)
df["average_user_rating"] = df["UserId"].apply(lambda x: s[x-1])
print(df)
```

Comment: The test works,Thanks! However when applying to my code, it gives me a Keyerror: 0. Because my dataframe start with a 0. How do I go about to fix this?

Comment: try: lambda x: s[x]

Comment: Already got it to work by merging, however, this also works, thanks!